# WSGI/Django: pass username back to Apache for access log

Tags: python, django, apache, authentication, mod-wsgi

My Django app, deployed in mod_wsgi under Apache using Django's standard WSGIHandler, authenticates users via form login on the Django side. So to Apache, the user is anonymous. This makes the Apache access log less useful.

Is there a way to pass the username back through the WSGI wrapper to Apache after handling the request, so that it appears in the Apache access log?

(Versions: Django 1.1.1, mod_wsgi 2.5, Apache 2.2.9)

Comment: This isn't trivially possible as far as I know, I'll be very interested if a valid answer is posted. I've used apache auth for my purposes.

Comment: This turned out to be trivially possible in nginx: app sets a response header; nginx includes that in the access log via [`log_format`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#log_format), and drops it before sending to client via [`uwsgi_hide_header`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule#uwsgi_hide_header)

Comment: Is there a solution for Apache as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only do it if using embedded mode and only if you use a separate package called apswigpy, which provides a Python binding for original Apache request object. The mod_wsgi package provides an optional mechanism for allowing original Apache request object to be passed as Python CObject reference in WSGI environment. You use that in conjunction with apswigpy something like:

```
from apache.httpd import request_rec
r = request_rec(environ['apache.request_rec'])
r.user = user
```

At least I think that will setup the appropriate information which access logging can then use.

You should really take this discussion over to the mod_wsgi mailing list.

Comment: Thanks; I started a thread there and am accepting this answer as the closest we're likely to get here. :)

Comment: Did the discussion there come up with anything better?

Comment: @GunnlaugurBriem I think I found [the thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/h4WpnUun7pk), but it's not clear if anything was actually implemented

Comment: Nothing was ever done to support it as it is such an extreme corner case that only a few people might want it, the work involved wasn't justifiable.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I don’t know how many people would want it, but I definitely would.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [mod_auth_tkt](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/). An `auth_tkt` is a signed cookie with the user id that Apache can understand. Your web application would have to [set the cookie](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/auth.auth_tkt.html#paste.auth.auth_tkt.AuthTicket) when the user logs in and out. Apache can derive a `REMOTE_USER` from the cookie, pass it to your web app or a non-Django web application running on the same server, include it in logs, whatever.

Comment: Sounds like just the *cough* ticket. One minor difficulty may be the binding to the IP, could cause issues to anyone behind load balanced proxies. Also may make it tough to reverse proxy your application.

Comment: No, it doesn't cause problems. The cookie is optionally bound to the remote user's IP address. You can pass that with an X- header or some other means depending on the nature of your proxy.

Comment: This does seem a fairly neat solution, actually; enables single-signon with other apps. Also would make it possible to log (and control) access to static media not handled by mod_wsgi; not a big thing for us but a nice added benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you're expecting, but you could use the username in your URL scheme. That way the user will be in the path section of your apache logs.

You'd need to modify your authentication so that auth-required responses are obvious in the apache logs, otherwise when viewing the logs you may attribute unauthenticated requests to authenticated users. E.g. return a temporary redirect to the login page if the request isn't authenticated.

Comment: Login view redirecting to /loggedin/<username> redirecting to settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. It's hacky, but I like it.

Comment: You're right — not what I'm expecting. :) Username in the URL is not acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but what's stopping you from creating some custom middleware that sets a cookie equal to the display name of the current user logged in. This middleware will run on every view, so even though technically the user could spoof his username to display whatever he wants it to display, it'll just be reset anyway and it's not like its a security risk because the username itself is just for log purposes, not at all related to the actual user logged in. This seems like a simple enough solution, and then Apache log can access cookies so that gives you easiest access. I know some people wouldn't like the idea of a given user spoofing his own username, but i think this is the most trivial solution that gets the job done. Especially, in my case, when it's an iPhone app and the user doesn't have any direct access to a javascript console or the cookies itself.

Comment: The spoofability is unnecessary: we now set a response header (not a cookie) in the app, and drop it in nginx before sending to the client, see [my comment on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244244/wsgi-django-pass-username-back-to-apache-for-access-log/10406967#comment-14514447)

Answer (score 0):

for latest (Django 2.x, Apache 2.4) Tested

source https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#apache-mod_wsgi-specific-configuration

you need to add `WSGIPassAuthorization on` in either server config, virtual host, directory or .htaccess

Comment: This is "authenticate with apache, how to pass that authentication thru wsgi". This is the opposite of what OP was asking.